# Why is @HeadMapping unavailable in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

The following annotations are included in the Spring Framework:
`@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`, `@PutMapping`, `@DeleteMapping` and `@PatchMapping` for standard Spring MVC controller methods. However `@HeadMapping` is not. What's the point about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [W3 Standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) for HEAD Request

```
9.4 HEAD

The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a 
message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP 
headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information 
sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining 
metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring 
the entity-body itself. This method is often used for testing hypertext 
links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.
```

It is a Request Method that is similar to `GET` but should not return a Body. Thus your `GET` method will effectively handle the `HEAD` method also but with the exception of not returning a response body.

So ideally you can use `@GetMapping` to handle `HEAD` request methods and can have a `Filter` to avoid returning the response back to the calling client as discussed in this [post](https://axelfontaine.com/blog/http-head.html)

Comment: Short answer from the referenced article: HEAD responses are supposed to include an accurate `Content-Length` header, so the work of building the GET response body likely can't be avoided. (The article then continues with some helpful implementation recommendations.)

Comment: @AvPinzur That's not true in general. It depends on your data source. If you have for example a file download from MongoDB GridFS you can read the length and all other metadata without reading the file.

Comment: @BenjaminM I agree, you can also get the length of a LOB in a RDBMS without fetching the entire content; the same applies to a file system resource, where you can get its size without opening it.

Answer (score 8):

You could always fall back to the `@RequestMapping`. This annotation supports all kind of HTTP methods. So `@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.HEAD })` does do the job!

---

If you really want to use `@HeadMapping`, you can create it yourself:

```
@target({ ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.HEAD})
public @interface HeadMapping {
    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class)
    String name() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class)
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class)
    String[] path() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class)
    String[] params() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class)
    String[] headers() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class)
    String[] consumes() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class)
    String[] produces() default {};
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: It should be a patch to Spring Boot. Actually, if it isn't [there](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues) in a week, I'll add it, give [Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2049986/jacob-van-lingen) credit and report back here